# Can I install the Secure Gateway client on a Raspberry PI

Tags: raspberry-pi, ibm-cloud, secure-gateway

I'm running Raspbian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy) on my Raspberry Pi.
Can I install the [Ubuntu IBM Secure Gateway client](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/SecureGateway/sg_025.html#sg_025)?

```
pi@raspberrypijps1 ~ $ sudo dpkg -i ibm-securegateway-client-1.4.1+client_amd64.deb
dpkg: error processing ibm-securegateway-client-1.4.1+client_amd64.deb (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ibm-securegateway-client-1.4.1+client_amd64.deb
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you have to compile during install. So I would guess that you might run into problems on an ARM architecture.

Comment: how does this relate to the missing file or directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Secure Gateway is available for i386, s390x and ppc64el architecture. Unfortunately, we do not have one for ARM architecture.